# How to store the output of case folding into data frame or list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, nlp

So I built up the function for Case Folding and Stemming, but the output is not what I wanted. This is the case of Text pre-Processing in Bahasa Indonesia, but you don't need to understand the language, my question is the format of the output. The code is shown below :

```
import re 
import string

#import StemmerFactory class
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory

#create stemmer
factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()

def case_fold(data, title = None):
        text = " ".join(words for words in data)
        text = text.lower() #lowercase
        text = re.sub(r"\d+", "", text) #remove numbers
        text = text.translate(str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)) #remove punctuation
        text = text.strip() #remove whitepace
        text = stemmer.stem(text) #stemming
        return text
```

I input the data like this

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Ini &Adalah [contoh]56 kalimat 57?','dengan} tanda. baca?!','seharusnya sih bagus tapi jelek !!!','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

print(case_fold(df['Brand']))
```

I got the output like this :

```
ini adalah contoh kalimat dengan tanda baca harus sih bagus tapi jelek audi a
```

While the output that I need is data frame like this :

```
                        Brand  
0   ini adalah contoh kalimat 
1           dengan tanda baca  
2  harus sih bagus tapi jelek  
3                      audi a
```

or list like this :

```
[ini adalah contoh kalimat',
 'dengan tanda baca',
 'harus sih bagus tapi jelek',
 'audi a']
```

Thank you so much for helping me, I work on this for hours, Because I not often build function by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you give to the function case_fold the entire list of sentences at once.
Then, in your function this line:

```
text = " ".join(words for words in data)
```

will take each sentence from your sentence list and concatenate them with each other into a single sentence containing all your sentences at once like this:

```
'Ini &Adalah [contoh]56 kalimat 57? dengan} tanda. baca?! seharusnya sih bagus tapi jelek !!! Audi A4'
```

All your processing will be done on this single sentence, hence returning a single stemmed and processed sentence.

To avoid this, you should call the function on each row of your dataframe using the apply function:

```
df["processed"] = df["Brand"].apply(case_fold)
```

You should also remove this line in your function that now is not necessary anymore:

```
text = " ".join(words for words in data)
```